# Count rows Android Room on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

learning Kotlin, proper app structure and stuff... Again... :)
So i have the following:

- Dao
- Repository
- ViewModel

**Dao Code**

```
    @Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from item_table ORDER BY Name ASC")
    fun getSortedItems(): LiveData<List<Item>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)

    @Query("DELETE FROM item_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()

}
```

**Repository**

```
class ItemRepository (private val itemDao: ItemDao) {


    val allItems: LiveData<List<Item>> = itemDao.getSortedItems()

    suspend fun insert(item: Item) {
        itemDao.insert(item)
    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ItemViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: ItemRepository
    val allItems: LiveData<List<Item>>


    init {
        val itemsDao = ItemDataBase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).itemDao()
        repository = ItemRepository(itemsDao)
        allItems = repository.allItems
    }


    fun insert(item: Item) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(item)
    }

}
```

I need to get current amount of rows in a table and i was thinking of something like this:
**add to Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM item_table")
    fun getAmount(): LiveData<Int>
```

**and then in Repo**

```
fun getAmount(): LiveData<Int>{
        return itemDao.getAmount()
    }
```

**and the same in ViewModel**

```
fun getAmount(): LiveData<Int> {
        return repository.getAmount()
    }
```

But again, should i also use an observer in Activity to get this value? Or, on the other hand, can i use just Int, while getting the table from DB as LiveData?

Comment: Can we use the above method of getting the select all one to get the list size. I think it is giving us the list already we can use size property to get the amount of rows. Let me know if my understanding towards your problem is right/wrong ?

Comment: Hi, well... i tried that. It returns null value. I think because it is a LivaData and it needs an observer. But also what if i won`t select everything from the table to the list but something specific, i will not get the full size of the table.

Comment: Are you getting the list? If you are getting the list values then the size is not an issue. Also, instead of LiveData object try with a kotlin observable delegate property